# function for deleting a node from a linked list not working properly

Tags: c, linked-list, free, singly-linked-list, function-definition

```
void del(struct node *l,int n) {
  struct node *temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp1=l;
  if (l==NULL) {
    printf("list already empty");
  }
  else if (n==1) {
    l=l->next;
    free(temp1);
  }
  else {
    struct node *temp2=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp2=l;
    int i,j=1;
    while (i<(n-1)) {
      temp1=temp1->next;
      i++;
    }
    while (j<n) {
      temp2=temp2->next;
      j++;
    }
    temp1->next=temp2->next;
    free(temp2);
  }
}
```

so this is a function i wrote for deleting an element from a singly linked list but it is not giving the required output. can someone please help me out?

Comment: It is or it is not giving  ? Can you show an example ?

Comment: first glance, I think it's very fishy you're allocating a new nodes in your delete function. Second glance, those are memory leaks. On success, `malloc` returns a pointer to a block of allocated memory. In the very next lines with `temp1/2 = l`, you're overwriting the pointer to the newly allocated blocks with `l`. Now, nothing points to the newly allocated block, and you can't hope to use it or eventually `free` it.

Comment: You're making this overly complicated IMO. I assume `n` tracks the number of nodes in the list? You really don't need that. For a simple linked list, your delete signature should be something like `bool deleteNode(node* head, node* nodeToDelete);` Then start at `head` and loop through each node in the list with the `->next` pointer. If your current node matches `nodeToDelete`, delete it and return true. If not found return false. The tricky parts are the corner cases which you are taking into consideration with `n`, but you can use pointer values to accomplish the same thing (valid or `NULL`)

Comment: There's no reason whatsoever to allocate new nodes in a delete function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is incorrect. At least it produces memory leaks due to these memory allocations that do not make a sense

```
struct node *temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *temp2=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The second parameter should have an unsigned integer type and positions in the list should start from 0.

The function should not issue any message. It is the caller of the function that will decide whether to issue a message after calling the function.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int del( struct node **head, size_t n ) 
{
    while ( *head != NULL && n-- )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    int success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        struct node *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

And if in main you declared a pointer to the head node like for example

```
struct node *head = NULL;

// filling the list
```

then the function can be called for example like

```
size_t n = some_position;
del( &head, n );
```

or

```
if ( del( &head, n ) )
{
    printf( "The node at position &zu is successfully deleted.\n", n );
}
```

where n is some position in the list.